# Find each word that occurs less than X number of times

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use Bash to search through a text file and only report back the words that occur less than X number of times. I tried this

```
cat abcd.txt | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c
```

But it reports back all the words and their counts. Plus, it also mixes up punctuations with words. For example, if there is a word "day" followed by ".", it reports back "day."

Comment: does it have to be in bash?

Comment: @AdamSmith Python works too. But the file is large(5GB+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Python is acceptable, you can use this script:

```
import sys  # for argument access

from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

c = Counter()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
            words = [word.strip(punctuation) for word in line.split()]
            c += Counter(words)

    print('\n'.join([k for k, v in c.items() if v < int(sys.argv[2])]))
```

and use it with:

```
$ python thisscript.py targetfilepath <COUNT>
```

where `<COUNT>` is the number of ocurrences you're interesting in limiting to.

Comment: Fantastic! Forgot how much nicer Python is than Bash.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk -F'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+' -v MAX=1 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++}END{a[""]=MAX+1;for(k in a) if(a[k]<=MAX) print k}' file.txt | sort
```

The field separator excludes all that isn't an ASCII letter or a digit `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` (feel free to choose which characters your consider as a part of a word).

The `-v MAX=1` switch defines the maximum allowed occurrences of a word.

Each word is stored in an associative array where the key is the word itself and the value the number of occurrences.

Once all the file is parsed, the `END{}` part displays the words (with less or equal than `MAX` number of occurrences).